# accessing xml children with namespaces

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I have this xml file and would like to get the d:DescriptionNL field out of it using PHP, only I can't seem to find out a way to get it. I already have gotten out the title, summary, and got as far as to say `$entry->content->{'m:properties'}` which gives me an object in return.

Does anyone here knowns if this is the right way to go or if I am totally going the wrong way?

Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="http://website.com" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">DigestedCatalogItems</title>
  <id>http://website.com</id>
  <updated>2014-07-09T12:55:29Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="DigestedCatalogItems" href="DigestedCatalogItems" />
  <entry>
    <id>http://website.com</id>
    <title type="text">Item Title</title>
    <summary type="html"></summary>
    <updated>2014-07-09T12:55:29Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name>Item</name>
    </author>
    <contributor>
      <uri>http://website.com</uri>
    </contributor>
    <link rel="edit" title="DigestedCatalogItems" href="DigestedCatalogItems('Car%20Plan')" />
    <category term="IBP.Catalog.Web.DigestedCatalogItems" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:DescriptionNL>Item description</d:DescriptionNL>
        <d:origin>Company</d:origin>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

This is the PHP code I have so far:

```
$response_xml_data = file_get_contents("http://website.com");

$data = simplexml_load_string($response_xml_data);

$array = $data->entry;

foreach($array as $row) {   
    //This get's me an stdClass object which I'm unable to explore any further
    echo $row->content->{'m:properties'};

    echo $row->author->name.' <br> ' . $row->content . '<br> <a target="_blank" href="'.$row->contributor->uri.'">'.$row->title.'</a>';

    echo '<br><br>';
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you have used so far, and the output

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are doing it the wrong way. If there is a namespace, you have to use [**`->children()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) method and add the prefix. Consider this example:

```
$response_xml_data = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="http://website.com" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">DigestedCatalogItems</title>
  <id>http://website.com</id>
  <updated>2014-07-09T12:55:29Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="DigestedCatalogItems" href="DigestedCatalogItems" />
  <entry>
    <id>http://website.com</id>
    <title type="text">Item Title</title>
    <summary type="html"></summary>
    <updated>2014-07-09T12:55:29Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name>Item</name>
    </author>
    <contributor>
      <uri>http://website.com</uri>
    </contributor>
    <link rel="edit" title="DigestedCatalogItems" href="DigestedCatalogItems('Car%20Plan')" />
    <category term="IBP.Catalog.Web.DigestedCatalogItems" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:DescriptionNL>Item description</d:DescriptionNL>
        <d:origin>Company</d:origin>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
</feed>
XML;

$data = simplexml_load_string($response_xml_data);


$author = $data->entry->author->name;
$contributor = $data->entry->contributor->uri;
$title = $data->entry->title;
// content children has namespaces
$content = $data->entry->content->children('m', true)->children('d', true);
$description = (string) $content->DescriptionNL;
$origin = (string) $content->origin;

echo $author . '<br/>';
echo $description . '<br/>';
echo $origin . '<br/>';
echo '<br/>';
echo "<a target='_blank' href='$contributor'>$title</a>";
```

The output should be something like:

```
Item
Item description
Company

Item Title
```

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/IDilqS)

Comment: Worked out fine! Thanks a lot!